# How to get intersection between two strings in PHP

Tags: php, string, compare, intersection

#### A problem description:

I have two strings and I need to find the length of intersection of them.

*Let's assume the both strings are Latin-ASCII and lower case.*

These are expected results:

```
$str1 = "lorem ipsum";
$str2 = "rem";
echo str_intersection($str1, $str2); // Expected result: 3

$str2 = "xzy";
echo str_intersection($str1, $str2); // Expected result: 0
```

---

#### My try to solve the problem:

I've tried to compare the strings using `array_intersect()` function this way:

```
$str_intersection = function(string $str1, string $str2): int {
   $arr1 = str_split($str1); // ['l','o','r','e','m',' ','i','p','s','u','m']
   $arr2 = str_split($str2); // ['r','e','m']

   return count(array_intersect($arr1, $arr2));
};

echo $str_intersection($str1, $str2); // Result: 4 (because of lo*REM* ipsu*M*)
```

But this way of comparing two strings is inappropriate because it compares occurrences of characters and not whole parts of strings as I need it.

In addition, the str_intersection() function designed in this way is not only inappropriate, but also very slow if I need to compare thousands of strings.

---

#### Example how I plan to use the needed function:

As requested I wrote a little example how I plan to use the string intersection function:

```
$strings = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet', 'consectetur'];
$needle = 'lo';
$intersections = [];
foreach ($strings as $str) {
    $intersections[] = str_intersection($str, $needle);
}
print_r($intersections);
```

Expected result (intersection "*highlighed*" as uppercase):

```
Array (
    [0] => 1 // LOrem
    [1] => 0 // ipsum
    [2] => 1 // doLOr
    [3] => 0 // sit
    [4] => 0 // amet
    [5] => 0 // consectetur
)
```

Comment: Compare for the first matching character and then compare until end.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Can you please expand how do you mean it pls?

Comment: This is quite a difficult problem that is poorly defined. Perhaps it might help if we knew what the function will be used for?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware OK I understand you might need more information. But I've been searching for such a function to more different projects. And the funcs like `str_contains()` or `str_start_with()` doesn't meet my requerments.

Comment: OK, I understand. An example would have been nice. The reason such a function doesn't standard come with PHP is the complexity of this problem. Any part of `$str1` could be a part of `$str2` and visa-versa. That requires many comparisons, and will never be very efficient. I though it we knew what you tried to achieve we could restrict the number of comparisons somewhat.

Comment: Question 1: for $str1 = "lorem ipsum"; and $str2 = "req";, is the result be "2" (matching re) ?

Comment: Question 2: for $str1 = "lorem ipsum"; and $str2 = "mmm";, shall the result be 2 or 1 ?

Comment: Question 3:  for $str1 = "lorem losum"; and $str2 = "los";, shall the result be 2 or 3 ? (I trust you want 3, right ?)

Comment: @KenLee 
Q1: result 2 is correct, 
Q2: shall be 0 because "mmm" is not part of the 1st string,
Q3: result 3 is correct

Comment: For Q2: But mmm 's first m matches the m in `lorem ipsum`, so.... ? should it be "1" (matched 1 time) or "2" (matched 2 times)?

Comment: Your addition contains a few errors: `$str_intersection()` should be `str_intersection()` and where your result contains 1 it should contain 2.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I've just improved the example a bit. I hope it'll help understand what results I except.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my attempt.

```
function str_intersection($str1, $str2)
{
   [$long, $short] = strlen($str1) > strlen($str2) ? [$str1, $str2] : [$str2, $str1];
   $shortLength = strlen($short);
   for ($length = $shortLength; $length > 0; $length--) {
       for ($offset = 0; $offset < $shortLength - 1; $offset++) {
           if (strpos($long, substr($short, $offset, $length)) !== false) return $length;
       }       
   }
   return 0;    
}

$str1 = "lorem ipsum";
$str2 = "rem";
echo str_intersection($str1, $str2) . PHP_EOL; // Expected result: 3

$str2 = "xzy";
echo str_intersection($str1, $str2) . PHP_EOL; // Expected result: 0
```

This outputs:

```
3
0
```

See: https://3v4l.org/7YW0R#v8.0.25

This function starts by sorting the input strings, so we know which one is the shortest. It then tries to find the longest part of this shortest string in the longer string. This is not very efficient, who can improve this?

Comment: I've just tested your code. 10k iterations took 0.035 sec. That's great!

Comment: Your code looks working well.

Answer (score 2):

Compare for the first matching character and then compare until end. For the case you want it case insensitive, I used *strtolower()*.

```
$countIntersections = function (string $source, string $snippet): int {
    $a = strtolower($source);
    $b = strtolower($snippet);

    $index = 0;
    $lengths = [];
    while ($index < strlen($a)) {
        $pos = strpos($a, $b[0], $index);
        if (false === $pos) break;
        $max = strlen($b);
        while ($max) {
            if (substr($a, $pos, $max) === substr($b, 0, $max)) {
                $lengths[] = $max;
                break;
            }
            $max--;
        }
        $index = $pos + 1;
    }

    return max([0, ...$lengths]);
};

var_dump($countIntersections('Lorem ipsum', 'rem'));
var_dump($countIntersections('Lorem ipsum', 'um'));
var_dump($countIntersections('Lorem ipsum', 'abc'));
```

#### Output

```
int(3)
int(2)
int(0)
```

Comment: The result is a boolean? I thought the result should be the length of the "intersection"?

Comment: Yes, the excepted result is the length of intersection - integer 0..x

Comment: Oh, I did not read carefully. I thought you just wanted to know if it intersects at all. Answer is updated. It will find the largest intersection.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I've just tested your code. 10k iterations took 0.015 sec. Great!

Comment: This will not work for `var_dump($countIntersections('rem', 'Lorem ipsum'));`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware No, therefore its parameters are source and snippet. And it its true, that the longer string does not intersect the shorter :D

Comment: But that's not what the question was, the question was about a true "intersection", although I have to agree that the question doesn't define that very well.

Comment: But could be easily fixed to swap inside function if needed. Just wanted to give the right hint with a working example. I expect every asker doing a bit effort himself.